# How to get metrics (scalar) samples more frequent than per epoch in tensorboard

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I'm trying to show the metrics of my training phase in Tensorboard. This is how I've setup my tensorboard at the moment:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=False,
                                    batch_size=28)

model.fit_generator(training_generator, epochs=80, steps_per_epoch=25, validation_steps=10,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard],
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    workers=3, use_multiprocessing=True,  shuffle=True)
```

And each epoch I can see a new `loss` and `acc` are added to the chart in tensorboard. But that's not frequent enough for me. I need to increase the frequency of the metrics calculated. Based on what the [documentation says](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard), I should be able to pass an `update_freq` parameter to control this behaviour. The default value for this parameter is `epoch` and other possible values are `batch`, or an integer that indicates the number of samples trained before metrics are recalculated by tensorboard.

As long as the `update_freq` is `epoch` (explicitly or by its default value), everything works fine. I see four charts by the names `epoch_acc`, `epoch_loss`, `epoch_val_acc`, and `epoch_val_loss`. And they are updated by each epoch. But the other values for `update_freq` seem not to work. No matter what other value I set for it (`batch` or any integer), I see two charts by the names `batch_acc` and `batch_loss` (no problem so far) but they hold only one data point. And they are not updated (I've waited like 10 epochs before giving up).

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on? Could it have anything to do with my model's structure?